# Add locale to laravel resource route

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have following route that expect locale in prefix

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}/admin', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {
    Route::resource('/profile', 'Admin\ProfileController', ['except' => ['edit', 'create', 'destroy', 'show', 'store']]);
});
```

The final route supposed to be like this:

```
www.example.com/en/admin/profile
and
www.example.com/en/admin/profile/1
```

while I can get index route `www.example.com/en/admin/profile`, but I cannot get update route `www.example.com/en/admin/profile/1` instead I have this

```
www.example.com/1/admin/profile/en
```

Here is how my routes are defined in blade

```
// Return index route correctly
{{route('profile.index', app()->getLocale())}}

//And 

{{route('profile.update', [$user->id, app()->getLocale()])}}
// Return update route wrong as I mentioned above.
```

**My question is:** How should I define my update route to return correct url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your parameters in wrong order. You need to send `locale` first and `$user->id` after that.

```
{{ route('profile.update', [app()->getLocale(), $user->id]) }}
```